# VirtualBox reinstalling & updating has left me with Too Many Network Adapters. How Do i remove them?

Tags: virtualbox, network-adapter, device-manager, windows-networking

I have too many network adapters. I have had to reinstall, repair VirtualBox a few times, and I have three NICs in my laptop.

I definitely don't need to have 14 bridged networking drivers though, and I cannot uninstall them. I only want to keep the new ones that came with VirtualBox 4.1.20.

When I go into the registry there are tons of places with these adapters. I have searched online up to 10 pages of Google, and VirtualBox forums, and no one has mentioned this problem nor explained how to delete these annoying extra network adapters.

Please offer some assistance or at least tell me how anybody else has dealt with this. I only need 1 host-only network adapter, 1 bridged networking adapter for each of my network cards. Take a look:

[image]

Comment: I've edited your post and added an image. Your original question posted the same URL for both images, but one is enough to convey the problem.

Comment: Can someone please help with this,  This issue has been an issue for many people, and is still an issue in the new VBox 4.2, Would really appreciate if someone can figure this out.  Microsoft's Gov Maharaj has said on Defrag that you have to do a system restore but the adapters are so old, that this is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

Try this procedure to cleanup useless adapter:

**1-** *Create a restore point before!*

**2-** Delete ghost adapters (displayed in soft colour): [underlined in yellow in my screen capture]

```
   Realtek Network Adapter #5, 6, 4, 7, 3 and 2
```

**3-** Disable Yellow Triangles Adapters [underlined in green in my screen capture]

```
   Realtek Network Adapter Vbox NO NUMBER, #5,4 
   *and* 
   Vbox Miniports #13,19
```

**4-** Reboot

**5-** KEEP Realtek Network Adapter NO NUMBER *unchanged*!

**6-** Trial and error process:

```
   Disable successively all Realtek Vbox bridged EXCEPT one 

   then launch VirtualBox to see if it's working with the remaining enabled adapter.

   Repeat this action until you'll find the right one.
```

[image: Your screen capture modified]

Hope this help. Let us know.